# Lookup and Replace a Single Letter in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

If I have a document open in eclipse, say a Java class file and I have a variable 'a' that is used multiple times through out the document, is there a way to look up just 'a' by itself because if I use the standard lookup Im going to get every word that contains 'a', I just want it to find 'a' by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the variable -> Rename